# Firebase Authentication: auth/argument-error - Incorrect argument provided in Google pop up sign in

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

  const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
      console.log(result.user);
    } catch (error: any) {
      if (error.code === "auth/argument-error") {
        console.error(
          "Firebase Authentication: auth/argument-error - Incorrect argument provided."
        );
        // Handle the error, e.g., show an error message to the user
      } else {
        console.error("Firebase Authentication:", error);
        // Handle other errors
      }
    }
```

I have a button that calls this funciton when clicked, but I am getting this error in my console

```
Firebase Authentication: auth/argument-error - Incorrect argument provided
```

I have tried all the fixes I could find online but nothing worked.There should be a Google sign-in pop up window, but nothing is happening when I click the button

Answer (score 0):

It was because I was using imports from "firebase/auth" and "firebase/auth/cordova" together. Don't make the same mistake as me guys